# Inserting information from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert the values into the new table here. However, I get (ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYSCHEMA.SYS_C007106) violated) which it states the `condo_id` as unique. Even though I am not inserting the `condo_id` into the new table. How can I resolve this?

```
insert into large_condo
    select location_num, unit_num, bdrms, baths, condo_fee, owner_num
      from condo_unit
     where sqr_ft > 1500;
```

Extra information:

The `condo_id` is the trigger.  How can I bypass the trigger?

Comment: It would be sensible if you showed the schema of the `large_condo` table because without that, we're having to guess what your problem is.  The outline schema should include all the columns and their types, plus any constraints (especially unique or primary key constraints), and any triggers on the table.  We probably don't need the schema of the `condo_unit` table.  Is there any danger that `large_condo` is a view on the `condo_unit` table?  (Pretty unlikely, but funnier things have been known!)

Comment: If you are using an `insert` statement that doesn't list the columns, that implies that you must be providing a value for every column (otherwise, Oracle would have no idea which subset of columns you were trying to populate).  If you're actually running the `insert` statement you posted here, you must be inserting a value for `condo_id`.  I don't know which column that is but give that primary keys are generally the first column of the table, I'd guess that you are trying to use `location_num` as the `condo_id` which probably doesn't make sense and isn't unique.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a  primary key on condo_unit in the table. If you are inserting same value again, you will face this error.

Or if you are inserting a null value in a NOT NULL column.
Or an index may be defined on it. Describe the table and verify them.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I can think of:

1. A default value is set for the `condo_id` column.  You should be able to see this by querying `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.
2. There is a trigger that sets a value for the `condo_id` column.  You can look for the trigger name in `USER_TRIGGERS` then view the trigger source in `USER_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone what I did was go to object browser and disabled the constraints